# How to call individual coefficients when they are given as an array?

Tags: python, regression, coefficients

[image]

I used reg.coef_ to get my coefficients for my linear regression (2 coefficients). But I cant figure out how to call each number individually so that I can assign them to variables, for example a and b, to build a function for my regression.

Comment: Please don't include code as an image. Include code as text.

Comment: It was mainly to show the kind of output I have, i didnt think the code itself mattered too much, my bad

Comment: If I read the image correctly, it looks as if something like "a = coef[0]0[0][0]" and "b = coeff[0][0][1]" might work.

Comment: a = coef_qt[0][0], b = coef_qt[0][1] this seemed to work, without the extra [0] in there, thank you i did not even consider it.